# 2 Variable Inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

While working on a Calculus worksheet with students a question came up that involved showing that any point along the tangent line to any point along the curve is greater than or equal to the curve itself. The answer was obvious,  but I struggled to formally prove the statement when I tried.
 In order to get a simple example, let's choose $\sin (x)$ In this case the tangent line at $x=x_0 = \sin(x_0) + \cos(x_0)(x-x_0)$, and thus we want to show that,  for any $0 \leq x, x_0 \leq \pi$,  $\sin x \leq \sin(x_0) + \cos(x-x_0)$.

For simplicity I'll use different variables,  but my question is the following: how can one prove that $\sin a \leq \sin(b) + \cos(b)(a-b) \qquad \forall a, b \in [0,\pi]$,  preferably using the methods of calculus (as elementary as possible)

Comment: What if it is tangent at an inflection point? Should there be some statement about the concavity at the point of tangency? Should the statement be limited to some interval about the point of tangency?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales : That's what I said in my answer; the result is true iff the curve is concave down at $x=a$. (If the curve is concave up, then the curve will be above the tangent line.)

Comment: OK, your answer has not loaded yet on my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent line of $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ will be above the curve $y=f(x)$ (locally) iff $f''(x)<0$. This is a consequence of the Taylor Remainder Theorem:

If $f''(x)$ is continuous on an open interval containing $x=a$,
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + f''(b) {(x-a)^2\over 2!} $$ for some $b$ between $x$ and $a$.

In your case, this translates into
$$f(x) = L_a(x) + f''(b) {(x-a)^2\over 2!} < L_a(x),$$
where $L_a(x)$ is the linearization of $f$ at $x=a$ (whose graph is the tangent line).

Comment: This is a fantastic result... I have never seen Taylor's Theorem written this way though. Do you know a source explaining that derivation of Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: Also, how are you defining "locally"? I specifically wanted to prove that the tangent line of $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ will be above the curve y=f(x)$ for *all* $x \in [0,\pi]$ (assuming also that $a \in [0,\pi]). Is your result strong enough to show this?

Comment: It's the Mean Value Theorem. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: Also, locally means: whenever $|x-a| < \varepsilon$, for some $\varepsilon>0$. The tangent line isn't above the rest of the curve in general; for instance, if $y=x^3 - 3x$, the tangent line at $x=-1$ won't be above the graph of the curve when $x$ is big. ($y'(-1)=0$.)