# Prove $f(x) \gt f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ if $x \ne x_0$

Tags: derivatives

If $f''(x) > 0$ on interval $(a,b)$, prove that for any $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and for every $x \in (a,b)$, where $x \ne x_0$, the following applies

$f(x) \gt f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$, if $x \ne x_0$.

Comment: Very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689184/2-variable-inequality/1689195#1689195

Answer (score 1):

WLOG suppose $x>x_0$.

Using MVT $f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(\xi)(x-x_0)$ for some $\xi\in(x_0,x)$. As $f''>0$, $f'$ is increasing, so, $f'(\xi)>f'(x_0)$.

Comment: The notation police will arrest you shortly.

Comment: That was close.

Comment: I tend to mix $\chi$ and $\xi$. What is your suggestion? $\zeta$?

Comment: Gotta work on your aspirations :-). (I am joking by the way, you are free to choose any notation you want, my wine was speaking :-)).

Comment: And I think $\xi$ is perfect.

Comment: WLOG? Never seen that one before. But MTV is familiar.

Comment: @RogelioMolina It means "without loss of generality" ,because $x$ and $x_0$ are interchangeable

Comment: It stands for Without Loss of Generality. I'm basically avoiding checking unnecessary cases. MVT stands for the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @RogelioMolina The other common one is "tfae", the following are equivalent

Comment: @AnthonyPeter, and Wilf-Fine: Thanks for the information! English is only my second language, and there are plenty of idiomatic expressions, shorthands, acronyms and what not that I must learn. Very much appreciated!

Comment: It is my second language also, and I know how hard it is to understand a simple phrase when you don't know what tfae suppose to mean. :)

Answer (score 0):

The function $\phi(x) = f(x)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is strictly convex on $(a,b)$ and
$\phi'(x_0) = 0$, so $x_0$ is a strict minimum of $\phi$ on $(a,b)$. That is,
$\phi(x) > \phi(x_0)$ for $x \in (a,b), x \neq x_0$.

Since $\phi(x_0) = f(x_0)$, we have the desired result.